# FastScroll and ListView padding

Tags: android

I want a layout where I have a ListView and my own view at the bottom of the screen. My problem is that the fastScrollIndicator does not account for the 50dp padding that I've put at the bottom of my ListView, and consequently becomes hidden by the view when I scroll to the bottom of the list. Any ideas what I can do here?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/buttonContainer" android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
  <ImageButton android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00000000" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/leftButton" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
  <ImageButton android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00000000" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/middleButton" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
  <ImageButton android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00000000" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/rightButton" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that padding is counted on the inside of the view, what you actually want to do in this case is to use a android:layout_marginBottom instead. Margins are counted from the outside of the view, and paddings are counted from the inside.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
/>
```